# Change firebase deploy directory

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Is there any way that I could change the directory for firebase deploy?

I want to change the 'notificationtest...' into another firebase directory name:

[image: I want to change the 'notificationtest...' into another firebase directory name]

I hope I am giving a clear question here though because I don't know how to explain it in proper words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `notificationtest-59f94` is your project ID, which you can't change after your project was created. If you want to deploy to a different URL, you will have to create another project.

Note that the console adds a suffix ("59f94" in your case) to new projects if another project already exists with the name you picked. So you will have to pick a unique name to prevent getting such a suffix.

And last I checked the project name had to have a `-` in it. So if you don' specify one yourself, the console will also add a suffix. Note though that these rules occasionally change, so be sure to check what the console says your project ID will become.

Comment: Can i delete the current project on firebase or it's ok to create another one on firebase linking with the same project on android studio? (I hope you get what I'm trying to say)

Comment: Yes, you can delete the project. And yes, it's also possible to create another project. To link it to your app, just create that app in the console, and then download its google-services-.json and add it to your app in Android Studio.